# User Profile Picture from AAD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have read the Profile Photo fetching API from Azure, and noticed if mailbox is not available for a user then, we can't fetch the photo by using the below API in both v1.0 and beta

`{ "error": { "code": "ErrorEntityNotFound", "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ImageNotFoundException' was thrown.", "innerError": { "date": "2024-03-11T15:12:51", "request-id": "b99d40f8-45b3-448f-ac11-c981a4208fd1", "client-request-id": "b99d40f8-45b3-448f-ac11-c981a4208fd1" } } }`

Is there any other way to get the profile photo which is uploaded in AAD for each user?

Comment: which API you are using? We have get profile phone API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#get-the-photo

Comment: Hi @TinyWang I have used below APIs: 

/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/photo/$value

and

/beta/users/{userPrincipalName}/photo/$value

Comment: @KarthikBalan Please edit your question and add this API along with more context for other users to answer.